# How does Maven different unit Test from integration Test?

Tags: unit-testing, maven, integration-testing

This is my project structure in `mvn`:

[image]

As you can notice, I have two classes in `src/test/java`

1. `CardValidtorIT.java` (THis is integration test)
2. `CardValidatorTest.java`  (This is Unit-Test)

when I run

`mvn package`

I notice only the `unit-test (CardValidatorTest.java)` is run

But when I run

`mvn integration-test`

I see both `unit-test` and `Integration tests` are run.

How does `mvn` know not to execute the `CardValidatorIT.java` when I run `mvn package`. That is, why it did not run `CardValidatoryIT.java`

Here is my `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>chapter14</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.agoncal.book.javaee7</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>
<groupId>org.agoncal.book.javaee7.chapter14</groupId> <artifactId>chapter14-service</artifactId> <version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId> <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId> <version>4.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId> <version>2.12.4</version>
<executions>
          <execution>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <goals>
<goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

P.S: I do know that I have a `integration-test` goal in mvn. but I have not tied the goal to which class should be run during integration test

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

See Maven Surefire.

This plugin is responsible for `mvn test` in Maven. The default configuration is coming into play. This means the class with the word `Test` will come into play when you run `mvn test` and in your case `mvn package`

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

When you run `mvn integration-test` the failsafe plugin is used. It's default inclusion/exclusion rules differ - by default it looks for the word `IT`, for example.

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

Note: It is odd to me that the test class `CardValidatorTest` is picked up when you run `mvn integration-test`. Based, on how I read the default inclusion and exclusion rules for the failsafe-plugin, I would not expect this. In fact, when I adapt your `pom.xml` to my own sample project, I don't see that behavior. Instead all `Test` classes are picked up with `mvn test` and `mvn package`. All `IT` classes are picked up with `mvn integration-test`. Are you sure you don't have some code level dependency on the two classes? Other than changed inclusion/exclusion rule, that's the only thing that I can think of that might cause them both to be picked up with `mvn test` or `mvn package`.

Comment: I am sure I don't have code level dependency. `mvn test` only runs 1 test (cardValidatorTest), `mvn package` runs only 1 test(CardValidatorTest) but `mvn integration-test` runs 2 tests (CardValidatorTest and CardValidatorIT). But your answer helped and the links too! Thanks

Comment: How can Maven know which tests are integrations tests *without* the `failsafe` plugin in the `pom`? They are run even though the project's pom doesn't have a `failsafe` plugin, it only has a `spring-boot-starter-parent` as its parent, and the integration tests use the `*IntegrationTest` suffix (which is not the default)

Answer (score 6):

The [Failsafe plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html) in Maven handles integration testing. By default, these are the [include patterns](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes) for integration tests:

```
"**/IT*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that start with "IT".
"**/*IT.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that end with "IT".
"**/*ITCase.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all java filenames that end with "ITCase".
```

Failsafe is not part of Maven's [default lifecycle bindings](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings), so integration tests like `CardValidatorIT`, which of course satisfies the default patterns, do not run as part of the lifecycle. This gets to Maven's opinionated conventions for which failures should fail the build and which tests should run all the time (fast unit tests with wide code coverage) vs. which tests should run less often (slow integration tests).

Of course, you can override conventions as you see fit.

Comment: and these have to be in `src/test/java/IT**.java` ? will this work? `src/main/java/IT**.java.` This can have name collisions with my class that have the pattern `IT**.java`

Comment: I've never tried, but I think you could do that by adding `configuration` elements to the plugins for what gets included/excluded at different parts of the lifecycle. That said, you are opening the door to a headache for yourself that I would consider far more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I prefer to src/test/java/ underlying surefire-plugin and src/integration-test/java/ underlying failsafe-plugin for UTs and ITs.   How can we do ?

Answer (score 2):

The integration-test build phase comes after the package build phase.  So "mvn package" will not reach the "integration-test" build phase.